# Hyper-v wasp sendkeys not working

Tags: powershell, automation, hyper-v, wasp

I'm trying to use WASP powershell module to send keys to Hyper-v client using this command. The syntaxes are ok since this works for notepad, etc.

Select-Window vmconnect | Send-Keys "Internal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focused control on in the window may be a button instead of a test input control.  You might need to send a hot-key combination to select the correct input.  I tried this with C# and found that if you launch "VMConnect.Exe" you have to wait a few seconds before it will accept input, then if You try to tab to the next control, it may be loading Virtual Machines for several seconds before you can select one...